# Como o Spring MVC identifica os arquivos Model, View e Controller?

Tags: java, mvc, spring

Queria saber como que o Spring faz o rastreamento desses arquivos. Até o momento eu sei que o Spring MVC tem o `DispatcherServlet` que fica responsável por mandar as requisições para os controladores que respondem a tal URL. Mas como o Spring faz pra retornar/renderizar a página (View) correta? Onde fica registrado o local delas?

Já vi em alguns projetos no GitHub que os devs declaram em um `.xml` um `InternalResourceViewResolver` com um prefixo e um sufixo, mas quando vou buscar esse prefixo (o suposto diretório) não tem nenhum arquivo da View, eles estão ou um diretório acima, ou em outro local.

Answer (score 0):

O prefixo e sufixo dos arquivos que vão ser observados podem ficar no Properties também:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= # Spring MVC view prefix.
spring.mvc.view.suffix= # Spring MVC view suffix.
```

Complementando, se estiveres em um projeto maven, é costumeiro que por padrão os arquivos estejam em "/src/main/webapp..."

Se puder postar mais informações do teu projeto nos ajudaria..